# How to download files in React from NodeJS server? (Getting files corrupted)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I would like to be able to send pdf files with nodejs to the frontend. But when I do this, I get an error and I can't open the file. This is the error (translation of error: an error occurred when loading the PDF document):
[image]

I think that all is well but still without working.

Here is the nodeJS code:

```js
routerTrainer.get("/download-training", verifyJWT, async (req, res) => {

  const { training_id } = req.headers;

  let training = await Training.findOne({
    where: { id: training_id },
  });

  if (training) {
   const path = "/home/gonsa02/Disk/Projects/";
   const dirname = "uploads/trainings/";
   res.download(`${path}${dirname}${training.file_id}`);
  }
});
```

And here is the React frontend code:

```js
const downloadTraining = async (id) => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    const JWT = new ClassJWT();
    const axiosReq = axios.create();
    await JWT.checkJWT();
    axiosReq
      .get(`${serverPath}/download-training`, {
        headers: {
          training_id: id,
          token: JWT.getToken(),
          responseType: "blob",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([res.data]));
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    fileReader.addEventListener("loadend", () => {
      const blobString = fileReader.result;
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = blobString;
      link.setAttribute("download", "file.pdf");
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
    });
  };
```

Don`t worry about all that have JWT like verifyJWT or ClassJWT, this are implementations of json web tokens and it works correctly.

If anyone know how to fix it, please let me know.

Comment: `${path}${dirname}${training.file_id}` may produce less `/` characters than expected. My first suspect would be that `dirname` doesn't end with a slash.

Comment: dirname is correct, I will write the variables to not get anyone confused

Comment: Why `res.download`, and not `res.sendFile`?

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky because I have tried it and it does not work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe you can try this

```js
fetch("filepath", {
  headers: headers
})
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.setAttribute("download", "file.pdf");
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
  })
```

I don't test it.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you get file with id so the name of the file missing extension .pdf you can try this code first and setting custom name

```
   res.download(`${path}${dirname}${training.file_id}` , "test.pdf);
```

if this is not working try to send file not download

```
var data =fs.readFileSync(`${path}${dirname}${training.file_id}`);
res.contentType("application/pdf");
res.send(data);
```

Comment: please check 2 thing 1.check your final directory and check name of your files is your file save with {id} or they have extensions like .pdf so if they have extension you should add this in your path 2. is to put fs.readFileSync in try catch and check if there is any error or not and console.log the data and check that the data print on your console

Comment: Final directory is correct and the file_id includes the extension of the file. Also if I open it through a linux terminal with xdg-open and the path that I get from `$ {path} $ {dirname} $ {training.file_id}` opens the pdf correctly, so in theory this is correct

Comment: Moreover if I console.log(response.data) recived in React frontend I get the following: data: "%PDF-1.5\n%����\n6 0 obj\n<<\n/Length 2168      \n/Filter /FlateDecode\n>>\nstream\nx��ZKs�6\u0012��W�M\u001c�\u0007�\u001b�}�8��+Q���r�... So the file is sent

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the response type to 'arraybuffer', `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` at least that work for me in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

if someone need anymore here is a react<->express without unmaintenenced libaries filedownlaoder the core code
React code after do click to Download:

```
  let options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/pdf",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
}
let res: any = await fetch(serverUrl + url, options)
const blob = await res.blob()
const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob]))

const link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = data;
link.setAttribute("download", bodyContent.fileName);
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
link.parentNode!.removeChild(link);
```

Express code within any route:

```
const fileName = uuidv4()+".pdf"
const invoice = await createInvoice([order], fileName) // could be a filepath like /src/pdfs/abc.pdf

var file = fs.createReadStream(invoice);
var stat = fs.statSync(invoice);
res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='+fileName);
file.pipe(res);
res.on("finish", ()=>{
  if (fs.existsSync(invoice)) { 
    fs.unlinkSync(invoice) //delete file
  }
})
```